# Spark Cassandra append dataset to table with null values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, insert-update, spark-cassandra-connector

I use [DataStax Spark connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) to fill a Cassandra cluster and process data in different jobs (due to some unsupported operations by Spark for streaming processing, such as double aggregation). So I want to store data in the same table for different jobs. Assuming that a first streaming job inserts a row in this table (using a foreach writer, because [the connector doesn't support streamed writing yet](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-510)).

```
INSERT INTO keyspace_name.table_name (id, col1, col2) VALUES ("test", 1, null);
```

What if I append (upsert) a dataset with a null column in it where there was already a non-null value for that row in Cassandra ?

```
// One row of the dataset = "test", null, 2
dataset.write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .option("keyspace", keyspace)
  .option("table", table)
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .save()
```

If I understand the [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlUpdate.html) correctly, the previous non-null value will be overwritten by the new null value ? If so, is there a way to keep existing 
 non-null values ? Or do I have to store the data in separate tables for each job ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Non Null values will be overwritten by null.

To avoid this behavior use `spark.cassandra.output.ignoreNulls = true`. This will cause all null values to be left as unset rather than bound.
[Write Tuning Parameters](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#write-tuning-parameters)

Comment: So with this parameter enabled, I will have the row `"test", 1 ,2` stored in my table after running my 2 jobs, right ?

Comment: yes.. since col1 is null in dataframe it will be ignored while writing..